# 表示したい文字が表示できない

Tags: swift

初心者です。swiftで簡単なおみくじアプリを作っています。
ViewController.swiftに

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var uranau: UIButton!
    @IBAction func Uranau(sender: UIButton) {
    }

    @IBAction func uranau(sender: UIButton) {
        var kekka = " "
        var kazu = arc4random_uniform(5)
        switch kazu {
        case 4:
            kekka = "大吉"
        case 3:
            kekka = "中吉"
        case 2:
            kekka = "小吉"
        case 1:
            kekka = "吉"
        case 0:
            kekka = "凶"
        default:
            kekka = "エラー"

        }
        print(kekka)
    }
```

と記載したら,本来なら大吉・中吉・小吉と出るところが、出ませんでした。
どこがおかしいのでしょうか？

Comment: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/27122/

Comment: リンク先の質問は、「ビルド時にエラーが出るが、何が間違っているのかわからない」と言うもの、この質問の趣旨は「ビルドエラーは出なくなったが実行させると期待通りの動作をしない」と言うものです。ソースコードもほとんど共通で強い関連性はあるものの、原因も対処方法も異なるので「重複」とは言えません。それともこれを「重複」とされる方は一つの質問が解決した後、同じスレの中でさらにどんどん質問を重ねるというスタイルを推奨されるのでしょうか。

Comment: @LePered'OO ケースバイケースですけど、この質問に関しては私は重複でよいと思っています。本質的に質問したいことは「おみくじの結果を表示したいけど上手くいかない」ということで変わっていないからです。「コンパイルエラーが出る」＞「print()が意図した通りに動かない」と来て、このままいくと手順ごとに似たような質問が投稿されるのではと思っています。それを防ぐには重複として、途中経過はすべて編集で、最終的にうまく動いたものだけが残った方が良いかと思いました。編集履歴に課程は残っていますし。

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi さん、そのようなご意見をお持ちの方がいるのであろうことは承知の上で、私の意見はこうですという表明です。これ以上続けられるのでしたら、metaに移行した方がいいと思います。

Answer (score 2):

先頭大文字小文字で同名の関数が二つあるようですが、大文字の方をUIにつなげていませんか？
大文字の方が不要であれば、一度コメントアウトしてみたらどうでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func uranau(sender: UIButton) {...}
```

StoryBoardを使っているのであれば、ここにAction接続するだけで動きますけれど。